# Error in aes_string(x = marketing_train$education, y = marketing_train$age) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

```
ggplot(marketing_train,aes_string(x=marketing_train$education, y=marketing_train$age) geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="cornsilk") theme_bw() xlab("marital") ylab("age") scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=10)) ggtitle("marketing") theme(text = element_text(size=15)))
```

i'm getting the below error for the code above please help

```
Error in aes_string(x = marketing_train$education, y = marketing_train$age)  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: Rather than `aes_string(x=marketing_train$education, y=marketing_train$age)`, you it shoudl look more like `aes(x=education, y=age)`. Not sure why you were using the `aes_string` rather than `aes`, but you should really not be using `$` with the aes function in general, instead use the `data=` parameters to the functions to specify the data source, and `aes()` should just point to column names. You might want to search for a basic ggplot2 tutorial before proceeding further.

Comment: It's also difficult to diagnose the problem without a sample of `marketing_train`.  If you post a sample of that table (use `dput`, don't format it like a table), we're much more likely to be able to help.